# How check in the database if there is a network login with the password that was entered?

Tags: c#, authentication

I wonder how can I create a code to check in the database if there is a network login with the password that i Entered. I'm doing this in the "Global.asax"

Thank you all!

EDIT: The code that i tried to write

```
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("Select * from Usuario where  = @UserID", conexao);
        comando.Connection = conexao;
        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@UserID";
        param.Value = login;
        comando.Parameters.Add(param);
```

I did something like this, but using Active Directory. Check it Out:

The task was to check in Active Directory if there is a network login

```
        try
        {

            using (var entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + dominio, dominio + "\\" + login, senha))
            {

                using (var directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry))
                {
                    matricula = TratarLDAPInjection(matricula);

                    directorySearcher.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + matricula + ")";

                    SearchResult result = directorySearcher.FindOne();

                    if (result == null)
                    {
                        throw new AguException(string.Format("Não é possível localizar o usuário de matrícula {0} no banco de dados da MyEnterprise.", matricula));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
          Response.Redirect("~/Erro.aspx");
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps a little more of detail and the code of what you have tried will help you.

Comment: Ok.

i'm doing a website, and i need to whenever a session is initiated, to be checked if there are in the database login and password informed. I tried doing this, but as I am a beginner, the code must be wrong. Anyway, I'll release it above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your sql query should be something like :

```
SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE [username]=@UserId AND [password]=@Password
```

Then you can bind the values @UserId and @Password, like you already did in your code.

(You need to replace [username] and [password] with the correct column names from your table)

EDIT :

You can get the result by using :

```
SqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader();
```